# Java Reg Expression

Tags: java, string

I have a question that how can achieve the following using java regexp.

Consider my string say:

```
a = "activity=play, then I play cricket"
```

Here my requirement is,

- if the above string `"activity=play"` then I should validate that string contains `"cricket"` as mentioned above.
- if the above string contains `"activity=noplay"` then nothing should be present at the last of the string. (i.e. The above string should have cricket at the last).

How should I do it?

Comment: probably not by regex but simple if statements placed in your string parsing method

Comment: .contains() is a valid and good way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a regular expression if you *just* want to see if a string *contains* another string. You could do something like so:

```
String str = "...";

boolean isValid = false;
if(str.contains("activity=play"))
    isValid = str.contains("cricket");
else if(str.contains("activity=noplay")
    isValid = !str.contains("cricket")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String reg = "activity=play.*cricket";
   String str = ".....";
   boolean isValide = str.matches(reg);
```